# Debugging Web Services in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, web-services, fedex

I am trying to use sample FedEx Web Service code written in VB.NET to retrieve shipping rates.

The call returned rate information, but it returned rates that are way too high and do not match those shown on their web site for the same shipping parameters.

Their support team is willing to investigate the discrepancy if I can provide them the XML data, SOAP transaction I presume, but I do not know how to get at this.

Can someone help?

Comment: 100 points to the person who can spoon feed me this answer such that I can get the XML transaction data myself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have used Fiddler in the past for monitoring http requests/responses. You may give this a try but i suggest you revisit the sample just to check it's logic. It could be as simple as a datatype issue or just missing some zeros at the end or you might be sending some wrong parameter.

Comment: Get Fiddler. http://www.fiddler2.com/ The screen is divided into 3 parts. The left part shows the URL and result. When you click on one of the items on the left pane, then the upper part of the right screen shows what was sent (click on the tab "Inspectors"), and the bottom right screen shows the returned values. I generally look at the "raw" for both the sent and receivled.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Web service Studio 2.0](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/webservicestudio20) can help you in this.. It can display XML & SOAP request responses and WSDL bindings of the given webservice.

And there is an [codeplex alternative](http://www.codeplex.com/WebserviceStudio) to test even WCF services .. Just give a try..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to just sniff the connection using WireShark (free download, wireshark.org).

From this, you could view the entire transaction between client and server, and see what it was sending.

Answer (score 0):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is your friend, here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fiddler or the WCF tracing tool:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx